# Ansible Backup Running-Config Module Error

Tags: automation, ansible, network-programming

The code below is my very simple playbook in which I'm trying to log into a switch, grab the running config and save it to a file.

I keep running into the error:

```
TASK [Get running config] *************************************************************
fatal: [imp1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Connection type ssh is not valid for this module"}
```

I've tried using modules 'ios_command" & "ios_config". Neither worked. I've confirmed I can indeed SSH to the switch via CLI.

```yaml
- name: Backup Cisco Switch
  hosts: SWITCHES
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    ansible_user: myuser
    ansible_password: mypassword

  tasks:
    - name: Get running config
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - show running-config
      register: config_output

    - name: Save running config to file
      copy:
        content: "{{ config_output.stdout[0] }}"
        dest: "/home/genesisjoec/Switch_Backups{{ inventory_hostname }}-running-config.txt"
```

Both modules, all which resulted in the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

From [`ios_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_command_module.html) module documentation:

> This module works with connection `network_cli`. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_ios.html

So, you can set the connection type either in your inventory, or using `vars` on a play level:

```yaml
- name: Backup Cisco Switch
  hosts: SWITCHES
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_user: myuser
    ansible_password: mypassword
    ansible_connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
  tasks:
    - name: Get running config
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - show running-config
      register: config_output

    - name: Save running config to file
      copy:
        content: "{{ config_output.stdout[0] }}"
        dest: "/home/genesisjoec/Switch_Backups{{ inventory_hostname }}
```